# Extract R Summary Using sed

Tags: regex, r, bash, sed

I want to convert the standard output of R's data.frame summary into a CSV using sed.

Let's say I have 5 columns of information that are separated by commas, and one of them is called duration.

```
...,       duration          , ...

..., Min.   : 0.000 ,...   

..., 1st Qu.: 2.000 ,...   

..., Median : 5.000 ,...    

..., Mean   : 6.004 ,... 

..., 3rd Qu.: 9.000 ,...   

..., Max.   :15.000 ,...    

..., NA's   :18711 ,...
```

How can I use sed to extract only the information contained after the colon and before the subsequent comma for each line? (Alternatively, substitute all the information between the colon and preceding comma with a blank spance).

Thank you!

Comment: While you can do this using `sed`, `awk` (or even `cut`) is more suitable in this case.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I'd encourage you to visit the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/) and refer to help on [asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: `summary` output would not have commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `awk` you can try something like:

```
awk -F, '{split($3,ary,/:/); print ary[2]}' input
```

Where you'll need to change `$3` with the column number of your duration column.

Comment: Is there also a way of specifying multiple columns using the split command, or would this be set inside of a loop if I wanted to extract information from every column?

Comment: You can split entire line based on different `delimiters` or a `regex` and pick up pieces you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

I would do a bit more in R. The output of summary() is kind of ugly, being a matrix of character values. This would extract the values from that table first as character values and then as numeric.

```
apply( summary(df1), 2, function(x) sapply( strsplit(x, ":"), "[[", 2))
      Year     Site1
 "2006  "  "1.000  "
 "2007  "  "1.625  "
 "2008  "  "2.600  "
 "2008  "  "2.283  "
 "2010  "  "2.975  "
 "2011  "  "3.100  "

apply( summary(df1), 2, function(x) as.numeric( sapply( strsplit(x, ":"), "[[", 2)))
          Year     Site1
[1,]      2006     1.000
[2,]      2007     1.625
[3,]      2008     2.600
[4,]      2008     2.283
[5,]      2010     2.975
[6,]      2011     3.100
```

"[[" is just an extraction function which is usually used in an infix syntax, but it can also be used in the more R-typical functional manner `"[["( . , .)`. Each individual value of the contents of the object created by `strsplit` will have its second argument extracted.

Comment: thank you for this! I'm not sure if it helped adm but it was exactly what I was looking for

Comment: I am pretty new to sapply. I understand the strsplit function but could you explain the "[[", 2 argument? Is that just something to do with the ugly output of summary()?

Comment: It's not an argument to `strplit` but is rather the function to be called on the values passed by `sapply` from `strsplit`'s result.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed "s/.*:\([^,]*\).*/\1/"
```

substitute (`s/.../.../`)

match everything up to and including the colon (`.*:`)

what is between the first `\(` and `\)` gets captured into `\1`, which can be used in the replacement

match (and capture) everything as long as it is not a comma (`[^,]*`)

match the rest of the line (so it gets replaced too) (`.*`)

and finally replace all what was matched before with the part you captured (`\1`)